# calling a method with jsf 2.0 ajax library

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf-2

I am working on an application where users will be evaluating a piece of art and filling out a review form as they go along. They may spend a substantial amount of time on the form, so I want to save it automatically for the user, say every 5 minutes. I was hoping I could use javascript and set a timer for the 5 minutes and then have it basically execute the entire form via ajax and I could save the data to the database in case the user gets disconnected, etc. Unfortunately I cannot seem to find any way to do this. Getting the model updated with the data is not a problem, but I can't figure out how to get it to invoke the method (similar to how the action normally would when it was submitted.)  I don't want or need it to re-render anything, just let me call a method to save the data. How can I do this?

**Problems implementing the solution**

I tried implementing the solution of the hidden command link but I'm getting some very strange behavior. I am not sure what is causing this. First, some background on the implementation.  Form #1 creates a bean (None scoped) and puts it into the flash, then redirects to Form #2. Form #2 is the big form I was writing about, where I want to implement the auto-save. Form #2 has a ViewScoped bean. In the PostConstruct for this bean, it retrieves the value from flash, and populates a property field.  So far so good. This works perfectly without the javascript. I can press the command button to submit the form, and all is well.  However, when I introduce the javascript, when it executes I get a null pointer exception from the variable that should have been populated from the flash by the PostConstruct.  How is this javascript interfering  with that?  Once I have populated the property of view scoped bean with the object, it should not matter if its removed from flash scope, right?   FYI if I remove ONLY the javascript code and leave everything else it goes back to working fine when I press the button to submit.

Form #1

```
    <h:form>
    ... bunch of form objects ...
    <h:commandButton "Start New" action="#{someRequestScopedBean.someMethod"/>
    </h:form>
```

code for someRequestScopedBean.Method:

```
    public String someMethod() {
        // bunch of logic here
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext()
                .getFlash()
                    .put("myFlashObj", myFlashObj);
        return "form2?faces-redirect=true";
    }
```

view scoped bean used in form 2:

```
    @ManagedBean
    @ViewScoped
    public class someViewScopedBean { 
        //bunch of properties here 

        @PostConstruct
        public void initialize() {
            this.myObject = (MyObject) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                           .getExternalContext()
                           .getFlash()
                           .get("myFlashObject");
        public void saveDraft() { 
            // save to database
        }
    }
```

Form 2 page:

```
    <h:outputScript library="javax.faces" name="jsf.js"/>
    <h:form id="myForm">

       ... whole bunch of fields here ... 

       ... real button for user to submit ... 
       <h:commandButton value="Submit myForm" 
                        action="#{someViewScopedBean.save}" />

       ... hidden button for auto-save by javascript ... 
       <h:commandLink id="hiddenSaveDraft" style="display: none;" 
                      action="#{someViewScopedBean.saveDraft}" >
              <f:ajax execute="@form" />
       </h:commandLink> 

       <script>
           function saveDraft() {
                document.getElementById('qForm:hiddenSaveDraft').onclick();
                window.setTimeout('saveDraft()',15000);
           }
           saveDraft();
       </script>

    </h:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the final solution, and the cause of problems I had implementing it the first time around.  It had to do with WHEN the javascript was being fired.  The script code was being fired at the exact point I placed the `<script></script>` block, which was before the page was completely loaded and probably before the DOM was complete. This was causing all kinds of nasty, including duplicate invocations of `@PostConstruct`.

I fixed it by using a javascript event listener to fire when the page was completely loaded. This is important because I am using facelets templating, and I didn't have access to the `<h:body onload=` attribute. The listener is a useful and elegant solution.  The script block can be placed anywhere in the page. Here is what the script block looks like:

```
    <script>

    function saveDraft() {
        document.getElementById('qForm:saveDraft').onclick();       
        window.setTimeout(saveDraft,300000);
    }

    function initSaveTimer(e) {
        window.setTimeout(saveDraft,300000);
    }

    this.addEventListener("load",initSaveTimer,true);

    </script>
```

This will invoke the hidden button every 5 minutes to save the form.

Comment: This is a solution to a different problem than initially asked.

Comment: Hi @Balus, not entirely. It solves my original problem, which was how to automatically call the save method.  I was actually trying to implement your suggestion, when I ran into the javascript problem. I'm new to SO; if I'm not handling the situation correctly, I'm interested in learning a better way. By the way, what happened to your original answer?

Answer (score 1):

Since you wrote down `Javascript` as one of your tags i'm going to assume you incorporate Client side `Javascript` code in your app.

First of all use a hidden `<h:commandButton/>` or a hidden <`h:inputText/>` ( I use the latter in cases where I need to hold some information regarding a certain variable)

In the form you are submitting add one of these:

```
<h:commandButton style="display:none" id="clickme">
  <f:ajax execute="@form">
</h:commandButton>

<h:inputText style="display:none" id="changeme">
  <f:ajax execute="@form">
</h:inputText>
```

In your `Javascript` code add this code to either click or change:

```
setInterval(function() { 
  document.getElementById("clickme").onclick();

}, 3000); // update every 3 seconds

setInterval(function() { 
  document.getElementById("changeme").onchange();
}, 3000); // update every 3 seconds
```

Both will work fine. Just make sure they are within the form you are updating.